# MarkLogic 10 - database restore from MarkLogic 7 - unable to search managed document in restored data

Tags: database-migration, marklogic, database-restore, marklogic-7, marklogic-10

I am upgrading `MarkLogic` from 7 to 10. I am trying to restore backup  from `MarkLogic 7` to `MarkLogic 10`. Database restored successfully but facing issues with managed documents. I verified managed documents history and it is present in the database. It returns nothing when I try to search for the latest version documents from managed documents using

`cts:search(fn:collection(),dls:documents-query());` .

When I tried to check document is managed with below query it returns true.

```
import module namespace dls = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/dls" at "/MarkLogic/dls.xqy";
dls:document-is-managed('/entity/[some ID].xml');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to perform a bulk upgrade operation on DLS documents from versions of MarkLogic prior to 8. [Full details here.](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/relnotes/chap4#id_65479)

Comment: Hello Rob, thanks a lot for your help. It solved my issue.

Comment: facing another issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57112441/managed-document-not-working-in-marklogic-10-after-xdmpdocument-insert